# How can i use $.map with Object.keys function to get the first value from array given for Object.keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this json array:

```
//val
0: {name: "jeg", class: "klase-jeg", id: "id-jeg"} 1: {age: 11, id: "jeg-id-11"} 2: {mail: "jeg mail", class: "jeg-klas-mail"}
```

and i want to get the first key of each json:

```
(name,age,mail)
```

This is my function:

```
$.map(val, Object.keys) //Result: ["name", "class", "id", "age", "id", "mail", "class"]
```

But the result is all the keys.

to get the first key from a json i used this:

```
obj = val[0]; Object.keys(obj)[0]); //Result: name
```

and i tried to use it with map but it didnt work :(

```
$.map(val, Object.keys[0]) //failed
```

i can use each or for, but i would like to know if can i use map with object.key to get the first key of each json.

Thanks!

Comment: The "first" key of each object will vary from browser to browser - object keys are unordered - will this change your requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: You're better off  just accessing the property you want rather than trying to get the "first" key when the first key may not actually be the key you want.

Comment: it doesnt metter the order because i just want to get the first key of each json whatever the order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `Object.keys` like this:

```js
const val = [
  {name: "jeg", class: "klase-jeg", id: "id-jeg"},
  {age: 11, id: "jeg-id-11"},
  {mail: "jeg mail", class: "jeg-klas-mail"}]

const firstKeys = val.map(a => Object.keys(a)[0]);
console.log(firstKeys)

/*
  In jquery:
  $.map(val, a => Object.keys(a)[0])
*/
```

`$.map(val, Object.keys[0])` will throw an error because `Object.keys` is a `function`, not an array.

Update: Please note that properties' order in objects is [not guaranteed in javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/)

Comment: i added a same answer an hour ago but deleted, because not sure about order of properties. because order is not guaranteed in object

Comment: it doesnt metter the order because i just want to get the first key of each json whatever the order

Comment: @CodeManiac I assumed OP wanted any first key decided by `Object.keys` (now confirmed). You're right, I should've probably mentioned that in the answer and now I'm stuck with -1 :(

Comment: @adiga I'm new asking here, can you tell me who did that -1 for your answer and what does it mean. (Is it permissible to ask this in a comment?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this :

assuming :

```
a = [{name: "jeg", class: "klase-jeg", id: "id-jeg"},{age: 11, id: "jeg-id-11"},{mail: "jeg mail", class: "jeg-klas-mail"}]
```

then do :

```
    a.map((el)=>{
    return Object.keys(el)[0];
    });
```

Hope it helps !